# emailing mysql select statement by python

Tags: python, mysql, email

I am trying to insert a select statement into an email. The table
has 10 rows and 3 columns but I'm not able to do it. Code and errors below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import csv
import MySQLdb
import pysftp
import smtplib
import sys
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
conn =  MySQLdb.connect(XXXX)
#Email Part1 Msg 
part1 = """
To: To Person <>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: SMTP HTML e-mail test
"""
sender = ''
receivers = 
x = conn.cursor()
query1=  ("""select * from table""")
smtpObj=smtplib.SMTP('smtp', 25)
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, x.execute(query1))
```

This is the error messsage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 33, in <module>
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, x.execute(query1))         
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 729, in sendmail
    esmtp_opts.append("size=%d" % len(msg))
TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len(
```

Comment: Separated code from description; clarified description text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass in a string as the 3rd argument to `smtpObj.sendmail()`. After you do `x.execute(query1)`, you have to fetch the results and turn them into a string.

```
x.execute(query1)
msg = ""
for row in x.fetchall():
    msg += str(row) # or however you turn a row into a string
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg)
```

Comment: It worked, Thank you, I actually selected a column from a table It was coming in a line with brackets and single quotes . Is this because of converting to string ? Is there a way to get each row in a new line  
this is the output i am getting 
 ('error in stored proc',)('test error',)('test error',)('test error',)(None,)('test error',)(